# Как изменить размер svg

Tags: svg

Как изменить размер этого svg? изменение width и height приводит к пропаданию/обрезанию картинки

```html
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<svg height="1024" width="1024" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <g>
        <title/>
            <g fill="#fff" id="svg_1" transform="translate(-10,1024) scale(0.1,-0.1) ">
                <path d="m4820,9439c-1036,-77 -1981,-503 -2723,-1228c-976,-952 -1444,-2300 -1271,-3654c216,-1693 1410,-3103 3050,-3602c1268,-386 2679,-157 3754,608c1321,941 2008,2502 1804,4100c-216,1693 -1410,3103 -3050,3602c-488,149 -1057,212 -1564,174zm331,-2689c222,-22 333,-57 383,-122c13,-18 34,-62 46,-98c26,-76 27,-163 11,-813c-10,-406 -4,-531 29,-621c39,-103 125,-150 201,-111c69,36 230,213 335,370c243,360 391,639 569,1070c36,85 84,141 134,154c20,6 303,11 651,12l615,2l52,-22c67,-30 93,-69 93,-140c0,-135 -141,-412 -383,-751c-33,-47 -158,-213 -277,-370c-263,-346 -320,-427 -360,-511c-50,-106 -38,-193 41,-296c23,-29 139,-146 258,-260c333,-319 484,-487 607,-671c88,-133 122,-231 108,-315c-7,-46 -53,-101 -105,-128c-62,-31 -157,-37 -680,-44l-495,-7l-80,27c-204,68 -340,181 -649,539c-171,198 -298,295 -386,296c-81,0 -184,-108 -228,-242c-30,-90 -41,-159 -50,-315c-11,-184 -33,-227 -146,-274c-41,-18 -551,-24 -686,-10c-271,30 -522,115 -771,262c-361,212 -582,402 -819,704c-412,526 -693,974 -1034,1650c-132,263 -287,603 -312,684c-25,84 11,153 93,179c28,9 184,14 544,19l505,5l59,-22c93,-36 132,-82 195,-235c54,-129 345,-713 436,-876c93,-165 192,-303 277,-385c105,-103 152,-128 226,-122c63,6 80,20 119,105c95,205 110,898 25,1170c-49,155 -122,214 -324,257c-35,8 -35,20 -3,67c78,112 217,166 482,188c145,12 575,13 694,1z" fill="#61B7B0" id="svg_2"/>
            </g>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: В Windows 10 можно редактировать изображение и изменить размер с сохранением пропорции

Comment: @hot_penguin: без сторонних программ? Похоже, что я отстал от жизни :(

Comment: @UModeL можно даже в Paint если не ошибаюсь, но лучше через стандартный просмотрщик изображений, он перебросит тебя на Paint 3D при нажатии на кнопку "редактировать"

Comment: @UModeL но лучше конечно через код xD

Answer (score 5, accepted):

- Во-первых, задайте `viewBox` с исходными размерами изображения;
- Во-вторых, уберите `width` и `height` из атрибутов;
- В-третьих, задайте нужные размеры в CSS или в атрибуте `style`.

```css
img {
  width: 150px; height: 150px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
/*
svg {
  width: 150px; height: 150px;
  border: 1px dashed red;
}
*/
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 1024 1024" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" style="width: 150px; height: 150px; border: 1px dashed red;">
  <g transform="translate(-10,1024) scale(0.1,-0.1)">
    <path fill="#61B7B0" d="m4820,9439c-1036,-77 -1981,-503 -2723,-1228c-976,-952 -1444,-2300 -1271,-3654c216,-1693 1410,-3103 3050,-3602c1268,-386 2679,-157 3754,608c1321,941 2008,2502 1804,4100c-216,1693 -1410,3103 -3050,3602c-488,149 -1057,212 -1564,174zm331,-2689c222,-22 333,-57 383,-122c13,-18 34,-62 46,-98c26,-76 27,-163 11,-813c-10,-406 -4,-531 29,-621c39,-103 125,-150 201,-111c69,36 230,213 335,370c243,360 391,639 569,1070c36,85 84,141 134,154c20,6 303,11 651,12l615,2l52,-22c67,-30 93,-69 93,-140c0,-135 -141,-412 -383,-751c-33,-47 -158,-213 -277,-370c-263,-346 -320,-427 -360,-511c-50,-106 -38,-193 41,-296c23,-29 139,-146 258,-260c333,-319 484,-487 607,-671c88,-133 122,-231 108,-315c-7,-46 -53,-101 -105,-128c-62,-31 -157,-37 -680,-44l-495,-7l-80,27c-204,68 -340,181 -649,539c-171,198 -298,295 -386,296c-81,0 -184,-108 -228,-242c-30,-90 -41,-159 -50,-315c-11,-184 -33,-227 -146,-274c-41,-18 -551,-24 -686,-10c-271,30 -522,115 -771,262c-361,212 -582,402 -819,704c-412,526 -693,974 -1034,1650c-132,263 -287,603 -312,684c-25,84 11,153 93,179c28,9 184,14 544,19l505,5l59,-22c93,-36 132,-82 195,-235c54,-129 345,-713 436,-876c93,-165 192,-303 277,-385c105,-103 152,-128 226,-122c63,6 80,20 119,105c95,205 110,898 25,1170c-49,155 -122,214 -324,257c-35,8 -35,20 -3,67c78,112 217,166 482,188c145,12 575,13 694,1z"/>
  </g>
</svg>

<img src="data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 1024 1024' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg'%3E%3Cg transform='translate(-10,1024) scale(0.1,-0.1)'%3E%3Cpath fill='%2361B7B0' d='m4820,9439c-1036,-77 -1981,-503 -2723,-1228c-976,-952 -1444,-2300 -1271,-3654c216,-1693 1410,-3103 3050,-3602c1268,-386 2679,-157 3754,608c1321,941 2008,2502 1804,4100c-216,1693 -1410,3103 -3050,3602c-488,149 -1057,212 -1564,174zm331,-2689c222,-22 333,-57 383,-122c13,-18 34,-62 46,-98c26,-76 27,-163 11,-813c-10,-406 -4,-531 29,-621c39,-103 125,-150 201,-111c69,36 230,213 335,370c243,360 391,639 569,1070c36,85 84,141 134,154c20,6 303,11 651,12l615,2l52,-22c67,-30 93,-69 93,-140c0,-135 -141,-412 -383,-751c-33,-47 -158,-213 -277,-370c-263,-346 -320,-427 -360,-511c-50,-106 -38,-193 41,-296c23,-29 139,-146 258,-260c333,-319 484,-487 607,-671c88,-133 122,-231 108,-315c-7,-46 -53,-101 -105,-128c-62,-31 -157,-37 -680,-44l-495,-7l-80,27c-204,68 -340,181 -649,539c-171,198 -298,295 -386,296c-81,0 -184,-108 -228,-242c-30,-90 -41,-159 -50,-315c-11,-184 -33,-227 -146,-274c-41,-18 -551,-24 -686,-10c-271,30 -522,115 -771,262c-361,212 -582,402 -819,704c-412,526 -693,974 -1034,1650c-132,263 -287,603 -312,684c-25,84 11,153 93,179c28,9 184,14 544,19l505,5l59,-22c93,-36 132,-82 195,-235c54,-129 345,-713 436,-876c93,-165 192,-303 277,-385c105,-103 152,-128 226,-122c63,6 80,20 119,105c95,205 110,898 25,1170c-49,155 -122,214 -324,257c-35,8 -35,20 -3,67c78,112 217,166 482,188c145,12 575,13 694,1z'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E">
```

---

*Пока отвечал на вопрос, выяснил нюанс, который лежит на поверхности, но всё же не так очевиден. Может кому будет полезно.*

#### SVG и camelCase

Очень часто, при написании и/или правке SVG кода, мы используем какие-либо IDE с редактором кода или онлайн-редакторы. Там удобно "на лету" просматривать и отлаживать код. Но, нужно быть внимательными, когда работаем такими инструментами.

**Всё дело в том, как именно подключается SVG для предпросмотра в таких средах.**

Код SVG по сути XML-разметка, которая чувствительна к регистру. Поэтому нужно знать, как правильно пишутся имена тегов, названия атрибутов, свойства и параметры. Если нет уверенности в правильности написанного, то лучше сразу свериться со справочником. Иначе, одна опечатка может в дальнейшем обернуться долгими поисками проблемы. И тут предпросмотр в редакторах может сыграть с нами злую шутку (в особенности это касается онлайн-редакторов).

Идеальным вариантом, для предпросмотра SVG кода, было бы сохранение этого кода в файл *.svg, с последующим подключением через `<img>`, `<object>`, `<iframe>` или `background-image: url()`, но... На практике, для сохранения быстродействия и возможности взаимодействия с элементами, измененный код отображается в теге `<svg>`, который встроен в HTML-документ. В чём же проблема?

HTML и XML, не смотря на внешнюю схожесть, всё же очень разные. И, следовательно, обрабатываются по-разному разными парсерами. Тут и возникает тот самый нюанс, ради которого столько букв.

**Внешние svg-файлы и svg закодированная в Base64 разбираются XML-парсером, inline-svg попадает на разбор к парсеру HTML.**

Как известно HTML лоялен к регистру не только тегов, но и атрибутов. Именно поэтому, написанный с ошибкой svg-код, легко пропускается и работает в предпросмотре. Но, будучи скопированным во внешний файл, с ним уже будет иметь дело более строгий XML-парсер, который такое безобразие не потерпит.

Внимательно относитесь к выбору редактора и средству предпросмотра. Запомните написание основных тегов и атрибутов и чаще сверяйтесь со справочниками. по возможности, проверьте код, сохранив его в отдельный файл и подключив через соответствующие теги.

*<sup>Спасибо [@MaximLensky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/308951/maximlensky) за то, что мотивировал меня на изыскания.</sup>*

Comment: а если svg интегрируется в код через тег img - как размер менять? При изменении размера img все так же обрезается svg

Comment: исправь сразу - так как не работает это всё равно ...`viewBox` вот так правильно

Comment: @Proshka: дополнил.